# Automatically selecting implementation based on Java version?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, guice

I've recently been messing around with an open-source Java web app.  I'm using JDK 7 locally but I know that the upstream builds using JDK 6.

I want to write some code that uses classes that only exist in JDK 7 (currently, `ThreadLocalRandom`).  I can do that on my local system just fine, but when I want to send patches upstream I have to hunt down any such references and translate them to the equivalent JDK6-safe code, which is a pain in the butt.

Is there a way to have both JDK6 and JDK7 source in the project, and have Eclipse automatically use the appropriate version at compile time based on the project target?  I would like something that's easy for both myself and the upstream maintainer, so nothing like weird build scripts or text replacement.

The project does use Guice, if that helps, although I think doing it at runtime might be too late (because then the maintainer wouldn't be able to compile using JDK6 tools).

I'm only at "dabbler" level in Java, so please use small words.

Comment: It is straightforward to have separate projects using Java 6 or 7 but not both in the same project.

Comment: Are you tied to eclipse? If not, I would recommend using [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). In IntelliJ, each project has a "Language Level". You can set that to 6 even if you use JDK7, and IntelliJ will fail to compile anything that's not available in Java 6 (it will show that `ThreadLocalRandom` does not exist)

Comment: @Alden: That's available in Eclipse too, it's just not what I want.  (In fact partly what prompted this is that upstream set this on the project, so my code stopped compiling.)  Ideally I would like to send patches that contain both implementations, and the project setting will determine which actually gets compiled, without errors.  So upstream can use 6 and I can use 7, and the only difference between us is the project setting, not the code itself.